# JavaScript function inside ()

Tags: javascript, closures

I have seen some functions inside **`(`**  **`)`**, and then I did a little research and found it was called **closures**. But I'm not really sure if that's what it is or closures are Classes.

What I mean is the following:

```
<script>(function e() { console.log("hello world"); })</script>
```

Why is the function `e()` `inside()`, what does that means?

Is it anyhow related to the following code?

```
function() C {
    e = function() { console.log("hello world"); };
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You're asking why the inner function has parentheses after it?

Comment: FYI, every function in JS is a closure, the `(...)` around them have nothing to do with that. They are used to force the JavaScript engine to interpret the function definition in a certain way (as a *function expression*).

Comment: Parentheses are just a way to encapsulate an expression, which is not a closure. A closure (really, just a function) is used to define variable scope (which, in JS, is basically function-scope).